# Asynchronous / non main thread initialization in Hilt?

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal, dagger-hilt

I currently have this code in my app module:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideMsalClient(@ApplicationContext context: Context): ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication {
    // ISSUE: this does NOT work, as the createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication method
    // may not be called from the main thread
    return PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
        context,
        R.raw.msal_config
    )
}
```

As I learned from the exception on runtime, `PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication` (part of the [Microsoft Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android), but my question is of general nature) may not be called from the main thread.

So, using Hilt, how can I create an object outside of the main thread / asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a **javax.inject.Provider** at the places where you want to inject the class? This should do it without any bigger pain and it won't make it crash when you inject it with **Provider** - you just have to ensure, that you won't call **.get()** of the Provider, when you are on the Main Thread.

Here is a minimalistic example.

**Classes that I used to mimic the problem:**

```kotlin
import android.os.Looper

class PublicClientApplication {
    fun createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(): ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication {
        throwOnMainThread("create")
        return ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication()
    }

    private fun throwOnMainThread(methodName: String) {
        check(Looper.myLooper() != Looper.getMainLooper()) { "method: $methodName may not be called from main thread." }
    }
    // just to make it compact here
    class ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication {
        fun foo() {
            println("Bla")
        }
    }
}
```

Dagger Binding Code:

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideISingleAccountPublicClientApplication(): ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication {
        return PublicClientApplication().createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication()
    }
```

**As Field Injection**:

```kotlin
    import javax.inject.Inject
    import javax.inject.Provider
    ...


    @Inject
    lateinit var singleAccountPublicClientApplication: Provider<ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication>
```

**With constructor injection**:

```kotlin
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Provider

class MyServiceClass @Inject constructor(
    @Inject private val accountPublicClientApplication: Provider<ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication>
) {
    fun doSomethingAuthenticatedWhichWontBeCalledOnMainThread() {
        accountPublicClientApplication.get().foo()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your Dagger binding code you are creating the instance on the main thread though? (never used directly Dagger, but that's how it looks like to me)

Comment: ah ok, guess the magic lies within the Provider<T, so the instance creation is deferred until it's first used and as the first use does not occur on the main thread, the instance is created on a non-main thread? Can one freely mix Dagger Provider with Hilt?

Comment: The provider is actually not even a Dagger Thing it is a Javax Dependency Injection Standard, every Framework that is JSR-330 compliant should work. Dagger Hilt is just the successor of Dagger 2.

Comment: Ah and yes, your guess is correct. :)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf - I forgot to mention it -  I tested and did the the Provider Code with Dagger Hilt. Works out of the box.

Comment: thanks for your reply and comment, accept as answer and bounty awarded :-)